# quotient ring (R/I) has multiplicative identity but R does not

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-group

Does there exist a quotient ring R/I (I-ideal) with a multiplicative identity such that R has no multiplicative identity ?If so please give example

Comment: Take a direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, and take $I$ to be the ideal of all elements with $0$ in the first coordinate.